# Where does one draw the line?

Tags: discussion

When a user posts a question about performing some certain tasks, one of the reasons that the question can be closed states, in part:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it requires step-by-step instructions for a process that is specific to a particular project,...

But how does one determine where the line is between giving enough information to answer the question, on the one hand, and giving "step-by-step instructions" on the other? Should the reputation of the questioner be a factor, that is to say that a question where the answer needs to be more detailed might be more acceptable from a user with low reputation, than from a user with a higher reputation? I recognize that the magnitude of the reputation a user has on the Blender SE site is not always a reliable indicator of the experience of the user,  but I find that this is often a useful indicator.

Comment: Note that this close reason will likely be removed in favor  the the built in "too broad" close reason. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/584/599

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/62/599